# Electric potential across dielectric interface

Tags: electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions, dielectric

The boundary conditions at the interface between two dissimilar dielectrics are well known:

http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/220/handouts/DielectricBoundaryConditions.pdf

They seem to be Neumann type boundary conditions. However, isn't the electric potential also continuous? This would form an additional Dirichlet boundary condition. We know that using both Neumann and Dirichlet boundary conditions overprescribes the system, so I just be misunderstanding something. If the electric potential is discontinuous across the boundary, then how does the potential change? In other words, what are the value of and mechanism for the discontinuity?

Answer (score 0):

The Maxwell equations in vacuum state that $$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \rho /  \epsilon_0 ~.$$ Here the polarization is just charge, more precisely, $$\nabla \cdot \vec P = -\rho ~.$$ The bound charge is not hidden in a dielectric constant is absorbed in an effective medium so $\rho$ is the free, let's assume there is none, plus the bound charge. Inside the dielectric $P$ is constant so the bound charge is zero, but at the boundary of two different dielectrics the discontinuity in polarisation appears as an interface charge. It is this interface charge that causes a jump in the electric field and at the interface.

Comment: Is there also a jump in the electric potential? I.e. is the potential discontinuous?

Comment: I looked into it more, and I’m convinced that the electric field jumps but the potential remains piecewise continuous across the interface.

Comment: @Ian That is correct. I edited my answer.